# IE will always go to Tunnelbear when opening new tab

Tags: vpn, internet-explorer, browser-tabs

I have Tunnelbear installed, but it is off, not even launched.

Now when I click open a new tab in IE 11 (on Windows 8.1), the title of the tab will show text beginning with Tunnelbear... briefly before going to my start page, which is Google.com.  It is too brief, most of the time just a flash, for me to catch what it is saying in full.  I turned on Fiddler and didn't catch any unexplained Http traffic.

When the Google.com page is shown, it is still the first page, ie the back arrow is not effective.

What has IE got to do with Tunnelbear, and where is this configuration set up located?  It's a bit eerie.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed Tunnelbear, sometimes these softwares overrides the default configuration of IE even if you have switched off. So whenever you open a new tab, it flashes with the Tunnelbear page. If you wish you set Google page to load while you open new tab, check the link [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-new-tab-homepage-internet-explorer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Thanks, but I have no problem with the home page.  The home page is still showing, just that there is a moment of some activity related to Tunnelbear.  What is it and where can I find it?  What configuration setting is involved?

Comment: I'm not too sure about it. Probably you can write to Tunnelbear

Answer (score 0):

Tunnelbear has two modes of operation.

For Android, it installs as a background process that intercepts all traffic, no matter which app is running.

For Windows, there is no background service for it, so they provide browser extensions for Chrome and Opera.

They explicitly do not support IE at this time.

Even if I am logged into Tunnelbear in one tab of Internet Explorer, it does not have an extension that utilizes it, so traffic from new tabs does not go through the VPN, as verified by going to http://www.grc.com and running Shields-Up.  It shows my native ISP's address, as opposed to Chrome and Opera which shows the VPN's exit node address.

As for the answer to the OP:  There must be something set in your IE installation causing this.  Some setting or maybe a 'New Tab' extension that is altering the normal operation of opening of a new tab.

So I would verify your settings and make sure your Home Page is set properly.
Check all add-ons to make sure they are not attempting to use it.